# How to only accept a String with certain characters in Java

Tags: java, string, filter

```
for (int i = 0; i < d.getFornavn().length(); i++) {
    char c = d.getFornavn().charAt(i);  
    if ((c > 'a' && c < 'z') || (c > 'A' && c < 'Z') || ( c == ' ' || c == '-')) {
        flag = true;
    }
}
```

Hi! I'm trying to make a function that checks a string if it only has certain characters (only a-z, A-Z, the norwegian letters å,æ,ø,Å,Æ,Ø, whitespace and hyphen, but I'm having some trouble with that. I tried doing what you see here, but it's not working how I hoped it would (I didn't implement the norwegian letters yet, because I'm clueless on how to do that).

I'm starting to think there must be a simpler way to check for this, but I haven't heard about anything.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What you have there is basically correct, maybe just needs a little debugging.  What part are you having "trouble" with?  Can you supply an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach you are using will give result based on **last character of your string** or **only one character**. Since it is setting flag for each char. To reject all invalid strings you can simply

```
bool flag = true;
for (int i = 0; i < d.getFornavn().length(); i++) {
    char c = d.getFornavn().charAt(i);  
    if ((!c > 'a' && c < 'z') && !(c > 'A' && c < 'Z') && ( c != ' ' || c != '-')) {
       flag = false;
       break;
    }
}
```

Accept only those strings which `flag true`

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regular expression:

```
flag = d.getFornavn().matches("[a-zA-zåæøÅÆØ -]+");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could search on a string

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ - åæøÅÆØ";
    String yourstr = "Ø123456";
    System.out.println(myfunc(s, yourstr));
}
private static boolean myfunc(String s, String yourstr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < yourstr.length(); i++) {
        char c = yourstr.charAt(i);  
        if (s.indexOf(c) > 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```